# Checking if an integer contains a certain digit in a for loop

Tags: python, iteration

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Write a code which computes the sum = 1/1 + ... 1/6 + 1/8 + ... +1/16 +... from 1 to 10000, skipping over the integers that contain the number 7.

Here is my code so far, I am stuck on trying to skip over the integers that contain the digit 7.

```
def int():
 sum=0
 for i in range(10000):
    if # integer contains digit==7:
        continue
    sum += 1/i
 return sum
```

Comment: `if '7' in str(i)`

Comment: On a separate note, when calculating the sum as `sum += 1/i`, make sum float by writing `sum =0.0`.

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur Why?

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur Declaring `sum` as a float won't force the operation's result to be stored as a float. You need to instead make sure that the operation itself _produces_ a float.

Comment: You both are correct. Not sure why I typed that. Instead, I was thinking - Don't start the range with 0.
Anyway, appreciate both of you to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
def int():

    sum=0
    for i in range(1,10000): # make sure range is from 1 to whatever. Otherwise, you'll a ZeroDivisionError
        if '7' in str(i): #convert i to string
            continue
        sum += 1/i
    return sum
print(int())
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check a digit in number use this

```py
if "7" in str(i)
```